# Python 3.6 Django Registration Redux SMTPAuthenticationError at /accounts/register/

Tags: python, django, redux, registration

[image]

Unable to Register despite trying several times please tell how do i fix it!
code :

```
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

EMAIL_HOST ='smtp.gmail.com'

EMAIL_HOST_USER = '*******@gmail.com'

EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD='**********'

EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Comment: I think your credentials are not correct

Comment: Do i have to add the hosts inside allowed_hosts=["gmail.com"] like that!!

Comment: No need. The error says that your username and password are invalid.

Comment: Despite adding the correct password and mail address the same error reappears!

Comment: Can you verify it by opening your email account with the credentials you have provided, lets say from your browser. Will it open?

Comment: Thanks for the replies Despite letting the less secured apps there errors seems to appear over n over! how do i fix it

Comment: Could you try it?

Comment: If you have followed the advice on the Google support website and it still doesn't work, then there isn't really anything we can do to help you. Since your chances of getting support from Google are very low, I suggest you choose a different provider to send your email.